# unable to use serial on CM4 using linux

Tags: pi-4, serial, compute-module-4

When i am trying to connect to my CM4 via serial on my linux desktop and i am unable to get any output from screen
i have ensured that enable_uart=1 is in my config.txt file

for clarafaction i am talking about a usb to uart cable [like this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/954)
[image]

output of sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
the uart pins are connected to gpio pins 14 and 15, i am expecting shell output, not a blank screen and the usb end is connected to my desktop
any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you clarify (by editing your question)?  Serial over USB emulates a serial link over the USB bus.  The enable_uart line enables a serial link using the UART on GPIO 14/15.

Comment: done, hopefully that helps

Comment: enable_uart is meaningless unless you have connected a serial link to GPIO 14/15.  Please say what each end of the USB to serial dongle is connected to.  It's not clear what is sending/receiving data and what you expect to see.

Comment: the uart pins are connected to gpio pins 14 and 15, i am expecting shell output, not a blank screen and the usb end is connected to my desktop

Comment: Remember to add clarifications to your question.  You still have not said why you expect output.  What is happening at both ends of the link.

Comment: Have you used `raspi-config` to enable a shell on the UART?

Comment: `the uart pins are connected to gpio pins 14 and 15` you probably connected TX to TX and RX to RX - a very common error